# How to count all values of a one column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to count all the instances of all values of col_a

for ex.

```
col_a
 A
 B
 C
 A
 D
 B
 A
```

Is there one line of code I can use that would tell me how many times each value (A,B,C,D) exist in that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution will be `value_counts`

```
df.col_a.value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `groupby` with `size`:

```
>>> df.groupby('col_a').size()
col_a
A    3
B    2
C    1
D    1
dtype: int64
>>>
```